# CSS grid: set height based on content

Tags: css, sass

I have a teaser component where I need to display text on top of image. I have used display: grid to achieve this. But I need to restrict the height based on the content height. Currently since the image is bigger it is showing the full image but I would like to display only a portion of the image based on the content height.

Current Result:
[image]

Expected Result:
[image]

Codepen:
[https://codepen.io/AnnieRoy/pen/xxMgOPM](https://stackoverflow.com)

Also I cannot give a fixed height instead it should grow based on the content. I know we can achieve using position: absolute but for certain reasons I am not able to use that.

I have tried using grid-auto-columns: min-content and grid-template-*. But this hides the image completely.

Sample Code Snippet

```
<div class="teaser">
  <div class="teaser-image">
    <img alt="img" src="https://static4.depositphotos.com/1003326/319/i/450/depositphotos_3191160-stock-photo-blurry-bright-background.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="teaser-content">
    <h2 class="teaser-title">Teaser</h2>
    <div class="teaser-desc">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sagittis tincidunt urna. Cras blandit ante ac erat facilisis, id laoreet eros sodales. Curabitur gravida, magna feugiat congue luctus, ex urna luctus erat, at viverra urna sapien eu quam. Nunc vitae dui et arcu luctus mattis. Curabitur semper quam vel odio fringilla, sed aliquam ex tempor. Etiam egestas risus in mauris congue, at placerat risus suscipit. Donec ullamcorper mi et tristique lacinia. Sed at tempus elit. Ut in turpis massa.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.teaser {
  display: grid;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.teaser > div {
  grid-area: 1/1;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Updated with sample code snippet

Comment: Hello, `grid` is probably not the right choice here. You just need some `padding` and a `background-image`.

Answer (score 1):

Using grid is probably not appropriate here.  Just standard CSS box model will do what you want.

A CSS background image would be simpler, but I see you are saying that's not possible to do.  This might work.

```css
.teaser {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.teaser-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.teaser-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="teaser">
  <div class="teaser-content">
    <h2 class="teaser-title">Teaser</h2>
    <div class="teaser-desc">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sagittis tincidunt urna. Cras blandit ante ac erat facilisis, id laoreet eros sodales. Curabitur gravida, magna feugiat congue luctus, ex urna luctus erat, at viverra urna sapien eu quam. Nunc vitae dui et arcu luctus mattis. Curabitur semper quam vel odio fringilla, sed aliquam ex tempor. Etiam egestas risus in mauris congue, at placerat risus suscipit. Donec ullamcorper mi et tristique lacinia. Sed at tempus elit. Ut in turpis massa.
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <img class="teaser-image"
       alt="img"
       src="https://static4.depositphotos.com/1003326/319/i/450/depositphotos_3191160-stock-photo-blurry-bright-background.jpg" />
</div>
```

However, you **can** use a CSS background image and just set that style in the HTML, if that is possible.  If you can do this it would greatly simplify things.

```css
.teaser {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="teaser" style="background-image: url(https://static4.depositphotos.com/1003326/319/i/450/depositphotos_3191160-stock-photo-blurry-bright-background.jpg)">
  <div class="teaser-content">
    <h2 class="teaser-title">Teaser</h2>
    <div class="teaser-desc">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sagittis tincidunt urna. Cras blandit ante ac erat facilisis, id laoreet eros sodales. Curabitur gravida, magna feugiat congue luctus, ex urna luctus erat, at viverra urna sapien eu quam. Nunc vitae dui et arcu luctus mattis. Curabitur semper quam vel odio fringilla, sed aliquam ex tempor. Etiam egestas risus in mauris congue, at placerat risus suscipit. Donec ullamcorper mi et tristique lacinia. Sed at tempus elit. Ut in turpis massa.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Doing it this way, there's no need for the `.teaser-content` element now - unless you need it for other reasons not related to this question.